# iPhone 4, iPad 1 - funny weird icons in Safari using icon fonts

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios4, safari

DEMO + screenshot from browserstack http://j2fed.com/funnyicons/

As you can see, insted of a black tag icon, Safari displays some kind of custom built in clock icon, how can I disable this weird behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emoji changed between iOS 4 and 5. This causes the character code mapping to change. I wouldn't worry about it too much though. iOS 4 usage is fewer than 1%

Comment: I have just found out that if the browser fails to load the font it would use the Emoji. Still dont know why it does fail. Thank you for your help.